# How to understand energy function in thin plate splines?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, matrix, math

guys! I have carried out some experiments using matlab warp tools from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22227-thin-plate-splines). But the results are not good, so I decide to read its original paper **Principal Warps: Thin-Plate Splines and the Decomposition of Deformations** from [here](http://www.engineering.uiowa.edu/~aip/papers/bookstein-89.pdf) to find reasons. However, I am stuck to part II.....

It says the energy function $\mathbf{I_f}$  is proportional to $\mathbf{WKW^T = V(L^{-1}_nKL^{-1}_n)V^T}$, then, I can not understand the whole first paragraph of part II:
[image]

Why does the pattern of y-displacements represent an expansion of lengths along y-axis? Actually, I know energy function, but I can not understand its relations to $\mathbf{WKW^T}$, then the pattern of displacements, and then the actions around x or y axis. So, I ask this question about energy function. Thanks a lot!